# Can i use Chromecast as a server?

Tags: node.js, chromecast

Studying the possibility to achieve the following:

- We have a CMS that from time to time posts to a web hook a media URL (video) (public internet hosted)
- This web hook post we would like to post directly to a ChromeCast which is plugged in to a TV

Questions:
1. Can a web server like nodeJS be installed on a chrome cast?
2. Is it possible to use for example DynamicDNS to link the Chromecast to a domain name so the post from the web hook can be made?

Comment: Did any of these answers solve your issue? If so, please mark the best answer as the accepted answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of that answer to indicate to the community that your question has been answered and then both you and the person who provided the answer will earn some reputation points that can lead to more privileges here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

ChromeCast has a sender API which allows you to "send" content to a specific Chromecast.  Right now, the sender API works on Android, IOS and Chrome OS.  You can read more about it here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/sender_apps.

And, here's how a receiver application that would receive your content on the ChromeCast would work: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps or if you're content is a standard type, then you can use a prebuilt receiver application without building your own.

To answer your specific questions:

> Can a web server like nodeJS be installed on a chrome cast?

No, not without enormous hacking and development yourself to basically take over the hardware somehow and get your own stuff to run on it.

> Is it possible to use for example DynamicDNS to link the Chromecast to
>   a domain name so the post from the web hook can be made?

Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

The chromecast has an [android like google chrome operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromecast#Operating_system). It is possible to [root](http://cord-cutters.wonderhowto.com/how-to/root-your-chromecast-0157253/) it, but you will not be able to (to my knowledge) get a server on it. I would suggest taking a look at the [Raspberry Pi](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00T2U7R7I). You should be able to run a slim server on it. After you get that set up it might be feasible to pass command line commands to chrome or another web browser to display the data you like. A browser is not necessary, but I'm not sure if you know of any other way to display the media.

A different approach would be to have a server anywhere (could be in your home) and have something like the raspberry pi (any computer for displaying the content) connect to a webpage hosted with that server. Using websockets something like [socket.io](http://socket.io/), you could set it up so that the server could send messages (url of video) to the browser session you have open. The javascript of your webpage would then use that message to open that url.